# Can't access Ubuntu 20.04 server on double NAT LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I've got a few devices on my LAN running different Linux distros:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- CentOS 7
- Fedora 33

They're all in the same subnet `192.168.50.0/24`. Network map: [image: Network map]

Until recently, from my PC (`Subnet 2`) I was able to access (`ssh`,`http`) all three devices.

The other day, I restarted the ubuntu box due to a prompt from the `motd`. After the restart I wasn't able to access (`ping`,`ssh`,`http`) into the ubuntu box any more. However, I can still access the ubuntu box **via** the other linux boxes. ie. Login to the centos box; Login to ubuntu box from the centos box.

There is something strange going on and I can't pin point to exactly what it is.

Any pointers or what I else I should try is greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

**Environment**

- OS: 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)

---

**Debugging Results**

Routing tables

```
ubuntu # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 src 192.168.50.2 metric 202
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.2 metric 202
192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.2 metric 100

centos # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp4s0
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.3

fedora # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.4 metric 100
```

Nmap subnet 1 from subnet 2:

```
pc-01 # nmap -v 192.168.50.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-27 17:13
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.1
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.5
Host is up (0.0090s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.3
Host is up (0.014s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.4
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 8.93 seconds
```

Nmap subnet 1 from subnet 1:

```
centos # nmap -v 192.168.50.0/24
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-27 18:15 AEDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.1
Host is up (0.00031s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.2
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.3
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.4
Host is up (-0.100s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.5
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 2.08 seconds
```

Nmap ubuntu box with `-Pn` switch from subnet 2

```
pc-01 # nmap -v -Pn 192.168.50.2
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-27 16:45
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 16:45
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 16:45, 0.23s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 16:45
Scanning 192.168.50.2 [1000 ports]
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 16:50, 323.24s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.2
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.50.2 are filtered
```

Firewalls

```
ubuntu # ufw status
Status: inactive

ubuntu # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Closing this in favor of the follow-up at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648551/cant-access-device-behind-double-nat-lan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened. But after I flashed my router (`192.168.50.1`), the issue disappeared. Despite the fact I rebooted the router multiple times while debugging the issue.

Maybe an ip renew command on the ubuntu box would have resolved the issue:

```
dhclient -r
```

I will not mark this as the correct answer until I have a clearer understanding of what caused it.

Comment: This does not appear to be the solution. As I'm running into the issue again and this didn't help.