# Can't access device behind Double NAT LAN

Tags: ubuntu, routing, vpn, nat, subnets

I've got a few devices on my LAN running different Linux distros:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- CentOS 7
- Fedora 33

They're all in the same subnet `192.168.50.0/24`. Network map: [image: Network map]

Until recently, from my PC (`192.168.200.0/24`) I was able to access (`ssh`,`http`) all three devices.

The other day, I restarted the ubuntu box due to a prompt from the `motd`. After the restart I wasn't able to access (`ping`,`ssh`,`http`) into the ubuntu box any more. However, I can still access the ubuntu box **via** the other linux boxes. ie. Login to the centos box; Then login to ubuntu box from the centos box.

What I've found out is if I run a **vpn tunnel** (wireguard server is on the ubuntu box) I was able to access this device directly without going through the centos box or fedora box.

Apart from the fact this device acts differently to the centos box and fedora box, what can I do in terms of routing that allows me to access this device directly without running a VPN tunnel?

Thanks everyone

---

**Environment**

- OS: 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)

---

**Debugging Results**

Routing tables

```
ubuntu # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 src 192.168.50.2 metric 202
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.2 metric 202
192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.2 metric 100

centos # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp4s0
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.3

fedora # ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.4 metric 100
```

Comment: If you switch off DHCP Server on your wireless access point 192.169.200.1 and connect the 192.168.50.0/24 network to its LAN port rather then its WAN port you can remove one layer of NAT immediately

Comment: @roaima I appreciate your concern about the double NAT. Presently it is purposefully in that configuration, although I will remove the double NAT when I run some ethernet wires all round

Comment: What's "subnet 2" mentioned in your question? It's not (obviously) shown on the diagram

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant the network behind NAT2. Updated to indicate the ip range

Comment: What is result of `ip a` (`ip addr show`) on the Ubuntu and CentOS boxes?

Comment: What OS are you running on the PC? How were you connecting to the Linux boxes prior to the reboot of the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: If you're getting an IP via Internet interface, it's actually a triple NAT LAN.  Are the Linux boxes using static IP addresses?